# Angularjs - How to run code when the entire app has loaded?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Starting by saying this is the first time I try AngularJs (1.6) and I am not experienced enough, so I could ask wrong questions.

So, recently, I start working on a project build on AngularJS 1.6.

The task I have to complete is to run a script in specific routes. Let's say, for now, the script is the following simple one:

```
alert('Hello World');
```

After a long time research, I found that I have to use the `$state` from which I can access the `$state.current.name` and then in my code, I can use an `if` statement or a `switch` statement for run my code.

The problem with that solution is that if I try to access the `$state.current.name` when my app loads, the value is an empty string.

To make sure, that the `$state.current.name` is returning a value at some point I did the following:

```
setTimeout(
    () => console.log($state.current.name),
    3000
);
```

and then I can see that I have the value I need.

Finally, I have also tried the lifecycle components methods, the `run()` method of the `modules` and finally the `resolver` in the routes, and none worked for me.

In any of the tries I did, the `$state.current.name` was empty, while, always worked when I used the `setTimeout`.

As a final solution I have find the following that is not elegant one:

```
var interval = setInterval(
    () => {
        if ( 0 !=== $state.current.name ) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            alert('Hello World');
        }
    },
    250
);
```

So, the actual question is, if there's any better solution to access the given route name.

**Edit #1**

I just give a try to this code:

```
// ...

require('angular')
    .module(config.appName, moduleCollection)
    .run(
        $state => console.log($state.current.name)
    );
```

and still getting empty string :(. Any other solution?

Comment: [`module.run`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#run) should be the right place. What did you try with `run`? How did it not work?

Comment: @Phil this is what I thought. To be honest I don't remember how I tried the `run()` yesterday, as I did a tone of experiments. From what I remember, when I did a `console.log(arguments)` in the `run()`  method, I took a big list of arguments, and none was related to the routes _(at least until the level I could search)_. Do you think I can inject `$state` in the `run()` method? I didn't find any reference to that.

Comment: You can inject any provider value in `run`

Comment: hmmm !! :) @Phil let me try and I will come back ! :) thanks.

Comment: @Phil I just updated my question. I give it a try, but yet, it is empty on `run` method. :(

Comment: You should use `$stateChangeStart` / `$stateChangeSuccess` event see https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki and for once can you confirm are you using `uiRouter`/`ngRoute`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **`uiRouter stateChange`** events:

There you can give a condition to check your state name:

```
if(toState.name == 'something')
{
  alert(toState);
  alert(fromState);
}
```

**when the `state` is changed successfully:**

You have to use them in `run` function

```
.run(['$state', '$rootScope', function($state, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(e, toState, toParams, 
  fromState, fromParams) {
        if(toState.name == 'something')
        {
          alert(toState);
          alert(fromState);
        }
    }); 

}])
```

**when the `state` change starts:**

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    alert(toState);
    alert(fromState);
});
```

[**Here is the Documentation**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)

Comment: thanks for your reply. Give me a minute to give a try, and then I am coming back again :)

Comment: That solution worked like a charm !! :) Thank you so much @Sravan.